# How to count the number of "unique columns" in each csv in R

Tags: r

I am a new user to R. I need your advice - 
I have around 100 csv files. The number of columns can change in each file. I am looking for help in identifying number of "unique columns" in each file - (If the file has a duplicate column , I want it to count as 1 unique column)

**file1.csv**

```
a,b,c,d
1,2,0,4
2,0,3,5
3,0,4,6
4,8,7,0
```

**file2.csv**

```
a,b,c,d,c
1,2,0,3,0
2,3,4,5,4
3,6,2,0,2
4,2,3,5,3
```

So technically, the code should give me 4 columns (a,b,c,d) for file1.csv and 4 columns for file2.csv (a,b,c,d - column c is duplicate).I know using the dim(df)[2] will give me number of columns in each file but if I have to do it for 100 files, how should I do it?

Comment: Thanks nrussel, how did you arrange those tables?

Comment: I just formatted them as code - select a section of text and click the curly braces symbol (`{}`) or hit Ctrl+K.

Comment: When there's a duplicated column, will the column name always be duplicated as well?

Comment: If its a duplicate column then yes, the name will be duplicated too

Answer (score 3):

If the column names are enough to determine duplicated columns, an easy and faster way to do this would be to read the first line of each file with `readLines()`, split according to the file separator (",") with `strsplit()`, and then find the length of the unique vector returned.

You can wrap this in a `sapply` or `lapply` to iterate over the file list.

```
files <- c("file1.csv", "file2.csv")
ncolumns <- sapply(files, function(f) {
    header.line <- readLines(f, n=1)
    length(unique(strsplit(header.line, ",")[[1]]))
})
ncolumns
# file1.csv file2.csv 
#         4         4
```

Assuming column names are enough to determine uniqueness, this will be faster since you don't have to load the whole csv file.

Comment: This seems like the most parsimonious and complete response, given the nature of the poster's question.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a loop that reads each file in turn. You don't want to open them all at the same time or you could run out of memory.

get file list:

```
f = list.files("./dir/", pattern="csv")
```

read files, find unique columns and write result to a variable:

```
answer = sapply(f, function(i){
   # read the file
   x = read.csv(i)
   # extract column names and then get the unique ones
   x = unique(colnames(x))
   # return the number of column names
   length(x)
})
```

You can then have a look at your file lengths:

```
# Summary statistics
summary(answer)
# Boxplot
boxplot(answer)
# Plot of number of columns vs names (probably messy with 100)
barplot(answer, names.arg=f)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the length() and unique() functions together to count the number of unique column names. For example:

```
data <- data.frame(matrix(c(1:12), nrow=3, ncol=4))
colnames(data) <- c("a","b","c","b")

length(unique(colnames(data)))
```

Depending on what your upload process is, you can try to integrate this into a loop or run as a batch process.

Comment: Thanks JFu. The command that you are sharing will help me only if I know how many number of rows and columns I have in each file right? What if I don't know that? I have 100 csv files and the number of rows can be 1000's and number columns can be 100's

Comment: Hi SAS, if you're asking about the first line in my code, that's just to create a example data. As long as you have your file is an object in R (like a dataframe), you can use colnames() to get the column names of the object. Then, length(unique()) will give you the number of unique column names.

Comment: The "b"-columns in your example are not really duplicated.

Answer (score 0):

In case the column names are not just decoration: `f` counts the number of unique columns of a data frame `X`:

```
f <- function( X )
{
  A <- mapply(c,as.list(X),colnames(X))

  sum( apply(A,2,function(col)
  {
    1 / sum( colSums( matrix(!(rep(col,ncol(A))==c(A)),nrow(A)) ) == 0 )
  } ) )
}
```

Examples:

```
> X1 <- data.frame( a = 1:3, b = 5:7, c = 3:1, d = 9:7  )

> X2 <- cbind( X1, c=4:2 )

> X3 <- cbind( X1, c=1:3 )

> X4 <- cbind( X1, e=5:7 )

> X5 <- cbind( X1, b=5:7 )
> X1
  a b c d
1 1 5 3 9
2 2 6 2 8
3 3 7 1 7
> X2
  a b c d c
1 1 5 3 9 4
2 2 6 2 8 3
3 3 7 1 7 2
> X3
  a b c d c
1 1 5 3 9 1
2 2 6 2 8 2
3 3 7 1 7 3
> X4
  a b c d e
1 1 5 3 9 5
2 2 6 2 8 6
3 3 7 1 7 7
> X5
  a b c d b
1 1 5 3 9 5
2 2 6 2 8 6
3 3 7 1 7 7
> 
> f(X1)
[1] 4
> f(X2)
[1] 5
> f(X3)
[1] 5
> f(X4)
[1] 5
> f(X5)
[1] 4
> f(cbind(X1,X1))
[1] 4
> f(cbind(X1,X5))
[1] 4
> f(cbind(X1,X2))
[1] 5
> f(cbind(X2,X3))
[1] 6
>
```